# Unfamiliar HTML Properties in Avada and Divi Themes

Tags: html

I have looked at the DOM code for two WordPress themes that have tag properties that follow a pattern I have never seen before. These themes fit into the category of "framework themes", but I have not seen this use of properties in themes that stick closer to the WordPress codex. Here is an example: 
    data-margin-right="0px" data-margin-left="0px" data-margin-top="31px" data-margin-bottom="31px"

When I do a Google search, it just picks up information about the default CSS rules: margin-left, margin-top, etc. I did figure out that CSS rules will override them, like it does other properties, within the normal specificity of CSS specifiers.

What is the story on these, ie. history, usage, constraints, etc? Should we look for this type of properties to show up in themes that more closely follow the WordPress codex. I have heard that WordPress is scheduled for a big technology change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called data attributes, which are custom attributes in the format of `data-*` used to attach more info to the html elements.

This link here gives good examples on how to use them: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Example:

```
<div id='el' data-my-attr='attr_value'></div>
```

**JavaScript**:

Most of the time, these info are used by JavaScript to fetch data and process them accordingly.

```
document.getElementById('el').dataset.myAttr; //Notice the property name uses CamelCase to replace the '-'s.

//Or using either of jQuery methods:
$('#el').data('myAttr');
$('#el').attr('data-my-attr);
```

**CSS**:

```
/* Use as selector */
div[data-my-attr='attr_value']{
    /* styles */
}
```

And apparently you can also fetch its values using attr():

```
#el::before{
  content: attr('data-my-attr');
}
```

So I guess one use for this is generating dynamic html and then set the CSS properties using the attr() in the CSS styles.

Comment: I find it odd that a Google search did not come up with any answers. I even added HTML5 to my query, because I figured that had something to do with it. I also figured that it might be related to ReactJS, but only one of the themes uses React. But,  the other theme uses jQuery, which fits your answer.

Comment: These are custom attributes, you can use whatever name you'd like. e.g. data-my-total-random-attr. jQuery does not perform special actions on these attributes. If you'd like to know which JavaScript or CSS styles are using it, you need to search through the code base.